# An explanation for unusual birth record

Tags: 19th-century, birth-records, kent

I'm trying to find an explanation for why Jane Ann Parry, born in 1857, was born in Kent.

Jane Ann Parry's parents are Thomas Parry and Jane Parry (I know this because of later census records 1861 and 1871 in Chester). She married Joseph Campbell in 1879 in Tranmere.

I looked into both Thomas Parry and Jane Parry (neé Jones) to see where they were born, and they were both born in Chester, and both live in Chester in 1851 and 1861. On census records in 1871, 1881, 1891 Jane is listed as being born in Chatham, Kent circa 1857.

Hence I am trying to figure out why they were in Brompton, near Chatham in Kent in 1857 but not in 1851 and 1861? Any insight or will this never be known? Even speculation is helpful.

Thomas 'occupation was as a ropemaker. I think since ropemaking was so often entwined with shipbuilding and there is a large shipyard in Chatham that may be an avenue of possibility. However,  I have no proof.

Comment: Is your Jane an only child? Looking at the birthplaces of all children gives you a head start on tracking a family's migration.

Comment: @Jan Murphy she was the first child and all the rest that came after were born in Chester

Comment: When did Jane's parents marry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chatham Dockyard was one of the main Royal Navy Dockyards. As a rope-maker, it's certainly possible that he was working there.

You might want to look at [Records of Royal Naval dockyard staff](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/royal-naval-dockyard-staff/) to see if Thomas appears in those records. That might lead to further clues for research.

For example, the pay books for Chatham Rope Yard, covering the years 1683 to 1865, are in the record series [ADM 42/287](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C4129307). That series has not been digitised, so you would need to either visit Kew in person, or employ someone to go there on your behalf.

---

If you can't get to London in person, it may be worth taking a look at the [Random Acts of Genealogical Kindness](https://www.raogk.org/) website to see if there's someone who would be able to check the records for you.

Comment: I'm finding the website rather tricky to use